# AWS amplify repository

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-amplify

I am trying to create an AWS Amplify project throught CloudFormation. However i am still wondering about the `Repository` attribute in the offical docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-amplify-app.html
and SDK
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-amplify/modules/createapprequest.html#repository

```json
"AmplifyApp": {
        "Type": "AWS::Amplify::App",
        "Properties": {
            "Name": {"Ref": "AmplifyProjectName"},
            "Repository": ?
        }
    }
```

Both linking a Codecommit repository and a S3 Bucket failed with the error

```
Resource handler returned message: "Invalid request provided: Repository provider not supported. (Service: Amplify, Status Code: 400, Request ID: a12af1b1-b7bd-4643-96af-3945de1a9fed, Extended Request ID: null)" (RequestToken: dc1dc831-f742-cb7d-a59a-d5d9a93ebd2a, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value for the `repository` key should be the URL to your source repository. Here are examples for different providers. Note that there is no trailing `.git` in the URLs:

- GitHub: `https://github.com/<user>/<repo>`
- BitBucket: `https://bitbucket.org/<user>/<repo>/`
- CodeCommit: `https://git-codecommit.<region>.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/<repo>`

Although I couldn't find any official documentation with examples for this parameter, you can find a blog post that uses the GitHub provider [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/deploy-aws-cloudformation-stacks-with-github-actions/) and a comment about BitBucket URLs [here](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-console/issues/154#issuecomment-535212939).

Comment: Nit: `eu-west-1` should be `<region>`.

Comment: Could you provide a link to sources of information, if any?

Comment: For the record, I tested creating an Amplify app and I tried connecting it to a GitHub repository and a CodeBuild repository.  The `repository` property on the app (I checked with the SDK) showed the URLs in the exact format as shown above by @berenbums.